# Zurb Block-Grid with Clearing

Tags: lightbox, zurb-foundation, shopify, liquid

I am using the latest version of Foundation (version 5) and when attempting to use a block grid to display images contained to a row I am not getting the desired result.
Where the images should be spanning 3 across there seem to be going 2 across and leaving blanks etc... please see the screen shot below

```
<div class="row">   
                    <div class="small-12 columns">
                        {% if product.images.size > 1 %}
                        <ul class="small-block-grid-3 clearing-thumbs" data-clearing>
                            {% for image in product.images offset:1 %}
                                <li><a href="{{ image.src | product_img_url: 'large' }}"><img src="{{ image.src | product_img_url: 'compact' }}" alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}" /></a></li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                        {% endif %} 
                    </div>
                </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have a link to the page? Perhaps a live demo? Based on the screenshot, it looks like there isn't enough room for all three to fit but it's impossible to say with being able to inspect the code.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue by using `[data-clearing] li {
    margin-right: 0px;
}`

Comment: Paul please add this as an answer - I've been looking high and low for this and it helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by using [data-clearing] li { margin-right: 0px; }